# python logging info level to a file

Tags: python, logging

I am starting using logging to keep track of what is going on in my code and started here:

https://realpython.com/python-logging/

According to that article this code should create and add a line to a log file called moses_data_extraction.log

```
import logging
import os

logging.basicConfig(filename='moses_data_extraction.log',
                    filemode='w',
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
                   level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('This will get logged to a file')
print(os.path.isfile('moses_data_extraction.log'))
```

the last line gives me FALSE

But the file is not created. Actually nothing happens, no file no error.

Some clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `print(os.path.isfile('moses_data_extraction.log'))` what is the output of this line ?

Comment: Ran the code. Got the file. Content: `28-Oct-21 13:13:10 - This will get logged to a file
`. Maybe you are looking for a wrong file name? Or you must refresh your file browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last print statement is giving you `True`, the file must be getting created in your current working directory.

To check the directory where the file would be present, you can check you current working directory using :

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Alternatively, you can specify full file path name in your code to place the log file at your desired location.

Comment: Indeed it was a problem with Jupyter Lab, not with logging. I am sorry.